# SELECT Nested within WITH Statements

Tags: sql

I'm not sure how to ask this without confusing the matter, but let me try and demonstrate with a simplified version of my code (as my code is far too long and most likely will confuse the issue at this point).

I have a `WITH` statement that defines several CTEs, and within the last CTE i have a `CASE` statement that takes the value of an earlier CTE, but for some reason it is throwing the error:

```
The multi-part identifier "RESULT1.total_revenue" could not be bound.
```

My code is approximately (simplified) as follows:

```
; with RESULT1 as (
        some code here which returns the columns: client_id, employee_name, total_revenue
        ),
    RESULT2 as (
        some code here which uses the client_id and employee_name from RESULT1 to get employee_team_names from another table employee_teams via a join
        ),
    RESULT3 as (
        some code here which then uses RESULT2 to then get the client_names from another table for each of the client_id found above
        ),
    RESULT4 as (
        now the problem here. I want to then take the client_names found above and do a join in another table to find clean_client_names
        however, if RESULT1.total_revenue is 0, then we can just put 'Not Needed' into the clean_client_name field
        my attempted code below which is throwing the error shown above

        select RESULT3.*,
                    (case when RESULT1.total_revenue = 0 then 'Not Needed' else clean_names_lookup_table.clean_client_name end) as clean_client_name
            from RESULT3
            left join clean_names_lookup_table
            on RESULT3.client_name = clean_names_lookup_table.client_name
        )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `JOIN` your `RESULT1` table in the `RESULT4` query, otherwise `RESULT1` is unknown. Presumably `RESULT3` has a field called `client_id` as well, in which case you would write:

```
    select RESULT3.*,
                (case when RESULT1.total_revenue = 0 then 'Not Needed' else clean_names_lookup_table.clean_client_name end) as clean_client_name
        from RESULT3
        join RESULT1 on RESULT1.client_id = RESULT3.client_id
        left join clean_names_lookup_table
        on RESULT3.client_name = clean_names_lookup_table.client_name
```

Answer (score 1):

This is your CTE:

```
 select RESULT3.*,
                (case when RESULT1.total_revenue = 0 then 'Not Needed' else clean_names_lookup_table.clean_client_name end) as clean_client_name
 from RESULT3 left join
      clean_names_lookup_table
      on RESULT3.client_name = clean_names_lookup_table.client_name
```

The reference `RESULT1` has not been defined.  You can only reference table aliases that are defined in the `FROM` clause.  And nothing in the `FROM` clause has that name.

You have two choices:

1. `JOIN` in `RESULT1` so the reference is valid.
2. Add the column that you want to `RESULT2` and `RESULT3` so it is available as part of `RESULT3`.